# Pergola Beam Span Weight Capacity

Tags: beam, pergola

I am building a Pergola with 6x6 posts and Beams attached to my house.  The dimensions are 16x14. There will be three post spaced 16 feet from my house.  The two end posts will be connected to the house via 2 8ft 6x6 beams with a 6x6 post in the middle supporting the joint and a ledger on the house.

The middle posts will need to have a single 16ft 6x6 between it and the house ledger, no support post at the midpoint like the edge beams.  Then there will be 12 pt 2x6 spanning from edge to edge carried by the three beams connected to the house.

I did a modulus calculation and the 16ft 6x6 has a modulus of 27.  The weight of the 2x6s is about 620 Lbs and has a modulus requirement of 13. So it looks like it will work.  I would love some feedback on the accuracy of my assessment.  I don't want that 16ft 6x6 falling on a family picnic.

Comment: Get a structural engineer that knows the code in your area.

Comment: Addition of a layout diagram would make your question much easier to get a clear understanding.